# max height not affecting visibility of border

Tags: html, css

The following

```html
<div style="max-height:0px; border:1px solid black; box-sizing:border-box; overflow:hidden;"></div>
```

results in a black line.

Why?

My problem: The box model comprises the borders, max-height is zero and overflowing portions should be invisible. So why do I see a border?

I would expect to see **nothing**, since I restict max-height to zero.

The same question applies to the following snippet:

```html
<div style="max-height:0px; border:1px solid black; box-sizing:border-box; overflow:hidden;padding-top:3px;"></div>
```

In both cases I would expect a completely whie page, since overflow is hidden, borders are part of the box and max-height is 0.

Where does my mental model of HTML go wrong?

Comment: Ahoy! How does `height` relate to `border` or `padding`? You can set `height: 0;` but that doesn't mean `border` will be 0 either!

Comment: Shouldn't in a box-sizing:border-box the border be part of the height? And then the max-height limit what I can see?

Answer (score 0):

border, margin and padding are not part of height.

You could wrap the div into another div and add `overflow:hidden;` to the parent div.

Comment: Hm. Does box-sizing:border-box not specify that border is part of the height? Am I wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're not defining the padding to control the inner height of the box layout. Here's a sample code for you to understand.

```
<div style="max-height:10px;
  border:1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding-top: 10px;">
</div>
```

I would suggest you to use classes instead of inline css. you can read more about css classes over here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp

Comment: You answer does not apply to my question but was helpful for a clarification of my question. My issue is not, why I see only one black line with no content, but why I see something at all. max-height is zero and I use border-box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use outline instead of border to get border inside an element:

```
outline: 1px solid red;
outline-offset: -1px;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking for an explanation, not for a solution. I need to correct my mental model...